# Between an open set and its closed subset

Tags: real-analysis, gn.general-topology

Suppose $F\subset V\subsetneq \mathbb {R}$ where $F$ is closed and $V$ is open. I want to show that $\exists$ an open set $U\subset \mathbb {R}$ satisfying $F\subset U\subset \overline {U}\subset V$. My proof is below, but I think it's problematic since I never use the condition that $F$ is closed.

For each $x\in F$, pick $r_{x}>0$ such that $(x-r_{x},x+r_{x})\subset V$. Then define $U=\bigcup\{(x-\frac {r_{x}}{2},x+\frac {r_{x}}{2})\}\subset V$. Then in fact, $F\subset U$. This is because countable union of open sets is open and $U$ is an open cover of $F$. It's trivial that $U\subset \overline{U}$. Now, what remains is to show that $\overline{U}\subset V$. First of all, $U\subset V$ since $U$ is just a collection of open intervals, and each one of them is in $V$. In fact, under this construction, $U\subsetneq V$. Therefore, for $y\in \overline{U}\setminus U$, $\exists u\in U$ such that $y\in B(u,r_{u})$. Take $r_{y}=r_{u}-d(y,u)$. Then $B(y,r_{y})$ is an open ball inside of $V$. Thus, $y\in V$ and $\overline{U}\subset V$.

Comment: You choose $r_x$, use it to define $U$, then define $r_y$ depending on $U$—that's circular.  (The claim that $U \subsetneq V$ also seems not to have been demonstrated.)  This is not research level.

Comment: A topological space is regular if and only if every open $V$ is the union of those opens $U\subseteq V$ satisfying $\overline U\subseteq V$. Then use that $\mathbb R\setminus F$ is regular.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე : I think the regularity is not enough. There are regular Hausdorff spaces that are not normal https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3874422/96609

Comment: @IosifPinelis In a regular space, for any nonempty open $V$ there is a nonempty open $U$ with $\overline U\subseteq V$, right?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე : Yes, in a regular space $X$, for any nonempty open $V$ there is a nonempty open $U$ with $\overline U\subseteq V$. But this is not enough for the normality of $X$, even if $X$ is Hausdorff. And the posted problem is equivalent to that of proving that the topological space $\mathbb R$ is normal.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Oh I see now, sorry! By some reason I was reasoning as if $F$ is open rather than closed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}\newcommand{\de}{\delta}\newcommand{\ol}{\overline}$The property of $\R$ that you want to prove is that the topological space $\R$ is [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space). [All metric spaces are perfectly normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space#Examples_of_normal_spaces) and hence normal. This proves your desired result.

That all metric spaces are normal immediately follows e.g. from Theorems 5.1.3 and 5.1.5 of the book by [Engelking](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3885380064): Theorem 5.1.3 (due to Stone; see also the short proof by [M. E. Rudin](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2035708)) states that every metrizable space is [paracompact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paracompact_space), and Theorem 5.1.5 (due to Dieudonné) states that every paracompact space is normal.

---

Here is an elementary, self-contained proof:

For each $n\in\Z$, the set
\begin{equation*}
    F_n:=F\cap[n,n+1] \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
is closed and bounded, and hence a compact subset of the open set $V$, so that there is some $\de_n\in(0,1)$ such that
\begin{equation*}
    \ol{U_n}\subseteq V, \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    U_n:=(F_n)_{\de_n}, \tag{3}
\end{equation*}
the open $\de_n$-neighborhood of $F_n$.

Let finally
\begin{equation*}
    U:=\bigcup_{n\in Z}U_n,  \tag{4}
\end{equation*}
so that $U$ is an open set containing $F$.

It remains to show that $\ol U\subseteq V$. Take any $x\in\ol U$, so that $x=\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k$ for some sequence $(x_k)$ in $U$. Without loss of generality, for some natural $N$ and all natural $k$ we have $x_k\in U\cap[N-1,N+1]$.
The conditions $F_n\subseteq[n,n+1]$, (3), and $\de_n\in(0,1)$ imply
\begin{equation*}
    \ol{U_n}\subseteq[n-1,n+2]. 
\end{equation*}
Hence, by (4), for all natural $k$ we have
\begin{equation*}
x_k\in\bigcup_{n\colon\,[n-1,n+2]\cap[N-1,N+1]\ne\emptyset}U_n\ 
\subseteq\bigcup_{n=N-3}^{N+2}U_n.  
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{equation*}
    x\in\bigcup_{n=N-3}^{N+2}\ol{U_n}\subseteq V, 
\end{equation*}
by (2). Thus, indeed $\ol U\subseteq V$. $\quad\Box$

(The part $V\ne\R$ of your condition $V\subsetneq\R$ is not needed here; looking at this condition, it seems that you are using $\subset$ for $\subseteq$.)